# How to run yolov2-lite tflite in coral edge TPU USB accelerator?

Tags: yolo, google-coral

I would like to make sure whether the following steps I executed to get the `tflite` of yolov2-lite model are correct or not?

**Step1** Saving graph and weights to protobuf file
`flow --model cfg/yolov2-tiny.cfg --load bin/yolov2-tiny.weights --savepb`.
This command created build_graph folder with yolov2-tiny.pb and yolov2-tiny.meta.

**Step2** Converting `pb` to `tflite`
I executed the below piece of code to get the `yolov2-tiny.tflite`

```
import tensorflow as tf  
localpb = 'yolov2-tiny.pb' 
tflite_file = 'yolov2-tiny.tflite'  
print("{} -> {}".format(localpb, tflite_file)) 
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
localpb,   
input_arrays= ['input'],   
output_arrays= ['output']    
)  
tflite_model = converter.convert()  
open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model)  
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)  
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

If the above steps I followed to get this tflite are correct, then please suggest me the command to run this tflite file in coral edge TPU USB accelerator.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, yolo models are supported by the edgetpu compiler as of now. I recommend using mobile_ssd models.

For future reference, your pipeline should be:

1) Train the model

2) Convert to tflite

3) Compiled for EdgeTPU (the step that actually delegates the work onto the TPU)

Comment: Thank you :). Also, is it possible to run the tflite models on Cloud TPU (I would like compare the performance between Edge coral TPU accelerator and Cloud TPUv2  )? Once again, thank you.

Comment: That I'm not sure of, although I can assure you the cloud TPU v2 are much, much faster lol The differences is 180 teraflops vs 4 teraflops but the cloud tpu will cost some dollars/hour

Comment: Thank you, Nam Vu.